# Where can I place the icon to get picked up by spring-boot-admin?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I am trying to replace default favicon and main page svg.
I placed them in resources:

```
assets/img/my-logo.svg
favicon.ico
```

and in application.yml

```
spring.boot.admin.ui.brand: "<img src='assets/img/my-logo.svg'><span>MyBoot Monitor</span>"
```

Still its showing 404 error.

Update: I realize that favicon cant be replaced like that.. But, spring.boot.admin.ui.brand SHOULD WORK as mentioned in [Reference](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.1/#spring-boot-admin-server).. Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have raised an issue here:

https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/903

Lets wait for the response :)

Answer (score 5):

To replace the images, you need to place your images in the resources folder of your project. The folder structure needs to be "META-INF/spring-boot-admin-server-ui/assets/img", otherwise it will not work.

[image]

Here I have added a PNG file, but you can use any type of image file.

Then you need to add the properties in the application.yml.

[image]

You can file more details about the properties at http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.2/#spring-boot-admin-server